# Fluent validation error: Enumeration yielded no results

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I would like to ask for your help. I want to validate my delete request class. The rule is:

> "Deletion allowed only for one element with the biggest price in
>   database for each type of product"

. repositoryEntities is not null but the Result is: Enumeration yielded no results.

Can you please check below code and let me know what is wrong?

```
private void CanIDelete(DeleteProductRequest entity, CustomContext context)
{
   var repositoryEntities = _productRepository.Queryable.Where(s => s.TypeOfProductId.Equals(entity.TypeOfProductId) && !s.IsDeleted);

   if (repositoryEntities != null)
   {
      var theBiggestPriceInDatabase = Decimal.MinValue;
      foreach (var repositoryEntity in repositoryEntities)
      {
        if (theBiggestPriceInDatabase < repositoryEntity.Price)
        {
            theBiggestPriceInDatabase = repositoryEntity.Price;
            continue;
        }
        if (entity.Price != theBiggestPriceInDatabase)
        {
            context.AddFailure("Deletion allowed only for one product 'with the biggest price' in database for each type of product");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description of what you are attempting to do.  Not even close.  Why don't you give your homework another go.

Comment: Firstly, cast repositoryEntities ToList(), secondly, in the if statement, check "repositoryEntities != null && repositoryEntities.Any()".